# Find vertical angle between two objects

Tags: mathematics, unreal-4, aiming

I'm working on a project that involves a battleship with multiple turrets on it. The turrets have limited movement on both horizontal and vertical axis. When checking if they can target the player I need to check if the player is within both fields of view.

I'm using the acos of the dot product to get the horizontal angle. For the vertical angle, I'm taking the X and Z components and ignoring the Y, creating two new vectors and repeating the process, but it seems a little buggy and not correct. I tried searching online but there is very little information for getting both angles.

The project is in Unreal and Z is the up axis.

WeaponTransform is the FTransform of the AActor.

TForward is the initial forward direction
WeaponTransform->GetRotation() * FVector::ForwardVector;

actorLocation is the location of the player using actor.GetActorLocation();

```
float hAngle = CalculateAngleBetween(tForward, actorLocation, WeaponTransform->GetLocation());
    inAngle = CheckAngle(hAngle, HMinAngle, HMaxAngle);

// This seems incorrect
FVector weaponForwardXZ = FVector(tForward.X, tForward.Z, 0.f);
    FVector actorLocationXZ = FVector(actorLocation.X, actorLocation.Z, 0.f);
    FVector weaponPositionXZ = FVector(WeaponTransform->GetLocation().X, WeaponTransform->GetLocation().Z, 0.f);
    float vAngle = CalculateAngleBetween(weaponForwardXZ, actorLocationXZ, weaponPositionXZ);
    inAngle = CheckAngle(vAngle, VMinAngle, VMaxAngle);

CalculateAngleBetween(FVector turretForward, FVector targetPosition, 
FVector turretPosition)
{
auto dir = targetPosition - turretPosition;
dir.Normalize();
auto safeForward = turretForward.GetSafeNormal();
auto cross = FVector::CrossProduct(dir, turretForward);
cross.Normalize();

float axisSign = FVector::DotProduct(cross, FVector::UpVector) >= 0.f ? 1.f : -1.f;

auto dot = FVector::DotProduct(dir, safeForward);
auto rad = FMath::Acos(dot) * axisSign;
return FMath::RadiansToDegrees(rad);
}
```

Comment: Dot product returns a float in [-1, 1], assuming vectors are normalised, which is not an angle in radians. So, what is "cos of the dot product"? Also, it's not clear which vectors are used when computing such a dot product, we can only make assumptions about that.

Comment: Can you show us what you're doing now, in code or in blueprints? The description you've given is a bit vague and doesn't 100% make sense the way it's been summarized (maybe you meant the arc-cosine of the dot product, not the cos? I presume you're normalizing a vector somewhere but that's not explicit...)

Comment: I updated the question with the code I`m using and put a comment where I think the bug is.

Comment: @DMGregory Any idea?

Comment: Since these turrets are on a battleship, is it reasonable to assume they might be rolling with the waves, and so the turret's vertical axis might not exactly match the world vertical z axis? Or is that not a concern for your use case?

Comment: @DMGregory For now, I can assume that will not happen. But if you have any advice for that case I will take that too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `WeaponTransform` is an [`FTransform`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FTransform/) representing the transformation of the turret base/pivot (against which we should be measuring any angular deviation), then I'd propose that we use this to move the calculation into the local coordinate system of this base to make things simpler.

```
// Get the offset from our position to the target, relative to our base.
FVector local = WeaponTransform->InverseTransformPositionNoScale(actorLocation);

// Discard the distance so we keep only the direction (a point on the unit sphere)
local.Normalize();

// The Z coordinate of that direction is the sine of the elevation angle.
float elevatonAngle = FMath::RadiansToDegrees(FMath::Asin(local.z));

// The XY coordinates give us a horizontal bearing relative to our local X+.
float relativeBearing = FMath::RadiansToDegrees(FMath::Atan2(local.y, local.x));
```

This is a standard [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) conversion that [you can find covered in many previous answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=spherical+coordinates).

Comment: @DMGegory I tried using this but both numbers are less than one. Do I need to do another calculation after this?

Comment: No. It could be that `WeaponTransform` refers to something other than what I suspected above, or it has been scaled non-uniformly. Or that `actorLocation` is not in the coordinate system that `InverseTransformPosition` expects. Can you add more details about how these inputs are defined?

Comment: I edited the initial post with information on where these values come from. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: "the AActor" could refer to *any* actor, for a reader who doesn't know your project intimately. Try giving more than just the data type. A labelled screenshot can often help in cases like this.

Comment: The AActor is player. I updated the post to include that information. My code is basically the same as what I have here, I just removed unrelated code, so a screenshot would be the same.